# How do I darken new mortar in a brick wall to match the older mortar?

Tags: brick, mortar

I had some bricks replaced. Unfortunately, the mortar is really light. How do I stain it a darker gray, so that it matches the original mortar? Is there a product that I can buy at a big box store?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Universal dyes might do what you want.  The trick is having the patience to test them to final color at dryness  Here's one [color brand](http://www.directcolors.com/concretedye/?gclid=CMLXgKyI2rUCFYZcMgodGXsA7A) (no association, haven't used them)

The source [here](http://www.nps.gov/hps/tps/briefs/brief02.htm#Mortar%20Type%20and%20Mix) (National Park Service) recommended against them (dyes), and they might diverge in color over time.  They suggested cleaning the surrounding area.

Diluted muratic acid brushing/power wash at a months's time would blend the old and new effectively (use protective gear/old cloths/gloves/goggles) hose down landscape plants beforehand)

Here's a tutorial for [cleaning mortar off brick from Fine Homebuilding](http://www.finehomebuilding.com/how-to/qa/removing-hardened-mortar-from-brick.aspx)